# ResourceBundle - Cannot work out how a properties file is read when it does not exist in the filesystem

Tags: java, properties, configuration, configuration-files, resourcebundle

I have an EJB 2.1 application that refers to a properties file to read a value from. The filename of the properties file is defined as

```
private static final String CONFIG_DIRECTORY = "config.";
private static final String PROPERTIES_FILE = CONFIG_DIRECTORY + "myapp";
```

To load and read the property from the properties file, the following call is made passing in PROPERTIES_FILE as the name of the propertyFileName

```
this.getProperties(PROPERTIES_FILE);
```

The `getProperties` method uses ResourceBundle to load the properties file as shown below.

```
public Properties getProperties (String propertyFileName) {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        ResourceBundle resourceBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle(propertyFileName);
        Enumeration<String> keys = resourceBundle.getKeys();

        while (keys.hasMoreElements()) {
            String key = (String)keys.nextElement();
            String value = resourceBundle.getString(key);
            properties.put(key, value);
        }
        return properties;
    }
```

Now i have spent ages trying to find a file called config.myapp everywhere within the application's file system but it does not exist. I even searched the whole filesystem for that file but it is not there. I looked inside all the folders, jar files etc but i cannot find a file called config.myapp

There is a folder called 'config' in the root directory of the application and within that folder there is a file called `myapp.properties` which does have the property that is being read by the application. Could it be be that `config.myapp` is actually referring to the `config/myapp.properties` file? If so how does that work?  Does `ResourceBundle` somehow translate `config.myapp` to `config/myapp.properties`?

Comment: i dnt see in above coce snippet as "PROPERTIES_FILE as the name of the propertyFileName" something you missed.

Comment: I mentioned that the method getProperties is called passing PROPERTIES_FILE as an argument. I have updated it to make more clearer.

Comment: You can just set a breakpoint and step into the method in a debugger. You'll see exactly where it's getting the file from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replacing the dots with slashes and appending .properties is the expected behavior.  From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html#getBundle%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Locale%29) for `ResourceBundle.getBundle`:

> Otherwise, getBundle attempts to locate a property resource file. It
>   generates a path name from the candidate bundle name by replacing all
>   "." characters with "/" and appending the string ".properties". It
>   attempts to find a "resource" with this name using
>   ClassLoader.getResource.

Answer (score 1):

Yes when you are using

```
ResourceBundle resourceBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle(propertyFileName)
```

no need to pass extention and also also you can pass the path as "folder name.file name"

ResourceBundle  will takecare of those conversion.

Answer (score 1):

ResourceBundle.getBundle() loads from your classpath, and it does [complex logic](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html#getBundle%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Locale,%20java.lang.ClassLoader,%20java.util.ResourceBundle.Control%29) to resolve the file (resource) properties name. Yes, it adds .properties at the end and uses a package

Briefly, the string you pass to getBundle() is called `basename` and the logic is:

> The baseName argument should be a fully qualified class name. However, for compatibility with earlier versions, Sun's Java SE Runtime Environments do not verify this, and so it is possible to access PropertyResourceBundles by specifying a path name (using "/") instead of a fully qualified class name (using ".").

So in your case, if you are passing the string "config.Myapp", the ResourceBundle will try to load from your classpath one of those resources (given that you have en_US locale):

1. config.MyResources.class
2. /config/Myapp.properties"
3. /config/Myapp_en.properties
4. config.Myapp_en_US.class
5. /config/Myapp_en_US.properties

This, because ResourceBundle is meant to be used for Internationalization (i18n), not for configuration.

If I may, I would suggest you to take a look at my little library to work with java properties: [owner API](http://lviggiano.github.com/owner/). (hope this is not taken as spam)